# How can I setting the position and width of suggestions in my own in Jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I am new to **jquery ui autocomplete**!

I found that the popup suggestion's **width** just like the **input field** which binded with **autocomplete plugin**,but my contents in suggestions may be longer than the **width** of suggestions popup list window. It was obviously that the width and position was calculate by the **autocomplete plugin**,so,is there a way to setting the width of popup suggestions to auto fit the width of my contents?

thank you very much~~!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hooking into the [`open`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-open) event provided by the Autocomplete widget. There, you can get a reference to the div that contains the suggestions and set it's width.

e.g. The following code worked for me just adding it using Firebug on the page linked above:

```
$( "#tags" ).bind( "autocompleteopen", function(event, ui) {
    var $suggestionsDiv = $(event.target).autocomplete('widget');
    $suggestionsDiv.css('width', 'auto'); // may not work cross browser
});
```

As noted in the comments, this may not be 100% cross browser compatible (I often have trouble with IE respecting `width: auto`, especially dynamically after the page has loaded), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my variant is not what you want, but I tired to find the solution to my situation, that is so close to your`s, and finally I`ve got it. So may be my solution can help someone.

All I wanted was to **set the width of suggestion list is same as width of input field**. We have an id for that? Yes.. if list of suggestions is static, we have a static id like #ui-id-1, but if we have dynamicly added list - there would be generated id like #ui-id-4598...

I didn`t find where and how such dynamic id was generated, so I`ve got little jQuery solution:

```
$('.ui-combobox-input').bind('click autocompleteopen', function(){
    var elementWidth = $(this).closest('.ui-combobox').css('width');
    //set suggestion list width
    $('ul.ui-autocomplete:visible').css({"width": elementWidth});
});
```

Note that this variant **will work if only one suggestion list is active at the moment**.